# Dynamic tableView Cell height swift IOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to create tableView which is suppose to auto resize the height according to the `messageLabel`. IOS8 has made this a lot of easier, however i can't seem to achieve this. So far i've created tableViewCell custom class with a xib file looking like below:

[image]

and then set the `messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

in the `viewController` i've set following in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and in the end the `delegate methods`

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int
{

    return 1

}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView:UITableView)->Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TwitterPlainCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TwitterPlainCell
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/507493048062713856/KaWKfdgW.jpeg")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f6f7f9")

    var name = "Olof Kajbjer"
    var userName = "@olofmCS"
    var topText = "\(name) \(userName)"
    var topCount = count(topText)
    var userCount = count(userName)
    var userNameLocation = topCount - userCount

    cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.dateLabel.text = "55m"

    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: topText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "PT Sans", size: 18.0)!])

    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(rgba: "#A6B0B5"), range: NSRange(location:userNameLocation,length:count(userName)))
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "PT Sans", size: 13)!, range: NSRange(location:userNameLocation,length:count(userName)))

    // set label Attribute

    cell.topLabel.attributedText = myMutableString


    cell.messageLabel.text = "I FUCKING LOST AGAINST @olofmCS ON AIM AWP IN OVERTIME... GGgg"

    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

The result of this can seen below, why is it not resizing the cell height?

[image]

Comment: What constraints do you have on the cell's subviews? That's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: any particular there is important of the labels?

Comment: Which label is the multi-line one? You need to make sure you have constraints from the top of the cell, through any views above or below the multi-line one, then down to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: BTW, I can't tell from your image that the cell didn't adjust its height correctly since I don't know where the bottom of the cell is in that image. All your text appears to be visible. Is the cell too tall?

Comment: @rdelmar the cell is too short and the separator indicator is appearing in the cell. This might actually be an iOS 8 bug for all I know. Happens all the time here.

Comment: @Schemetrical Auto-sizing cells work fine for me. I haven't had any trouble with them (as far as sizing the cells anyway -- there are problems with scrolling to a particular indexPath for instance).

Comment: the messageLabel is the multi line one. what constraints is important to have?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the bottom constraint i had to set it to `>=` or another value